# PDO, Injection and conserving server resources

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm refactoring PHP code to move from mysql_* and mysqli_* functions to PDO, and would like to accomplish this as efficiently as possible.

I use a file I call 'core.common.php'. I initializes the PDO database access object, has $_SESSION management features, and other features such as generic message and error notification functions (in the form of s.)  I use the MsgBox() and ErrBox() functions extensively while developing and debugging.  This file gets included at the top of every PHP-generated web page.

I have managed, at least through *some* testing, to successfully pass the PDO object (by injecting the PDO object in the __construct method) to classes that require database access.

It seems to me that this approach, while it still works so far, would only apply to each visitor of the site...  Each visitor can use the same PDO connector throughout all pages they visit on the site.

My real questions are...
What happens when there are many visitors ??  Does each get their own PDO instance ?  Would this mean that there would be many instances of database connections ?

The reason I'm asking is the host I currently use has "limited my resource usage" due to...  according to them...  "excessive resource usage".  It is a "shared server".  They suggest upgrading to a VPS (Virtual Private Server), and, of course at additional cost.

Is the host scamming me for more $$ ??
What, in the eyes of the Pros here, would be my best approach to this issue ?
And...  Absolutely for all...  Be critical and specific.

Any ideas are greatly welcomed !

Comment: If you were using excessive resources using mysql or mysqli, using PDO would be no different. If you've already got it working using mysqli, why refactor everything to PDO?

Comment: *Does each get their own PDO instance ?* yes they do. But it shpouldn't be a problem untill you get 1000 users at the same time I mean same 5 minute period, not same day :-) So usually you have no problem with server performance even if it is VPS. The problem ususally is the way you write your code in php and quesies you send.

Comment: If you are running anything but a static site you should be on a VPS anyhow. They are about the same price as a **good** shared plan if you don't need a ton of resources (read <=1gb of RAM and about 20GB of disk).

Comment: @Mike... Refactoring is not only for PDO, but there are things I have learned since I originally wrote the classes that will make them much more efficient.

Comment: @prodigitalson... The only thing I see when accessing the Resource Usage section on their cPanel is Entry/Exit line chart hitting the maximum.  I have asked the host for detailed reasons for their decision.  Entry/Exit (at least to me) means visitors.  Nothing there specifying database connects.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens when there are many visitors ??

*Exactly* the same thing that happened with mysql and mysqli functions.

> Does each get their own PDO instance ?

Yes. In a way.

> Would this mean that there would be many instances of database connections ?

Yes. Just like it was with mysql functions.

> the host I currently use has "limited my resource usage" due to... according to them... "excessive resource usage".

Make sure there is only one connection per script instance. According to your description it is already so, but just to be sure. That could be only issue with PDO. Also turn off persistent connection if used.

Regarding other aspects of this excessive usage, you better start a separate question, to ask recommendations on how to profile your code to get to the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you.  I made sure the classes only use one connection per script, but each one was creating its own connection...  Now, getting them all to use only one connection by injection.